# taking log of command output from inside script not working as expected

Tags: linux, bash

first, have try following script for execute sequence of commands

```
#! /bin/bash

echo "command1 going to execute"
command1

echo "command2 going to execute"
command2

echo "command3 going to execute"
command3
.......................so on...
```

And take log of output form above script as follows

```
 ./test.sh | tee test_$(date "+%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S").log
```

so i can see it on terminal and parallel log it in .log file. It's work fine.

Now i make some changes in script for simply execute the script like `./test.sh` and script internally take log.So no need to give extra argument during running script.

changes as follows

```
 #! /bin/bash
execute_all_cmd()
{
    echo "command1 going to execute"
    command1

    echo "command2 going to execute"
    command2

    echo "command3 going to execute"
    command3
    .......................so on...
}

now=$(date "+%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S")
LOGFILE="test_$now.log"
touch $LOGFILE
chmod 777 "${LOGFILE}"

execute_all_cmd 2>&1 | tee $LOGFILE
```

when run script by `./test.sh` then nothing happen,prompt comes after some seconds and i can see file generated but not data in file(size 0K).

So what is going wrong here?

**Update**: result of how my command executed using `set -/+x`

```
++ date +%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S
+ now=2014-03-19_22:24:20
+ LOGFILE=test_2014-03-19_22:24:20.log
+ touch test_2014-03-19_22:24:20.log
+ chmod 777 test_2014-03-19_22:24:20.log
+ execute_all_cmd
+ tee test_2014-03-19_22:24:20.log
+ set +x
```

**Update**

Found one interesting thing that my function `execute_all_cmd` in original script contain around 900 lines (here i just pasted few line for example). So i tried with few lines let say around 200 and commented other lines. surprise it worked! Now UN comment some more lines and it's worked up to 500 lines after that same problem.

So my question

is there any limit for number of lines in bash function?

Comment: I had tried your given code it is working fine in my system.

Comment: you are right but sadly here it's not working

Comment: Did you able to see the output in your terminal?

Comment: No, Nothing shown on my terminal

Comment: Put set -x in top of the script and set +x in end of the script and check till how many commands are executed in the terminal and say the result.

Comment: @Kalanidhi see result in question window as you suggested.

Comment: I had executed, here the function is not properly executing? when i executed the following lines is printed before set+x,+ echo 'command1 going to execute'
command1 going to execute
+ echo 'command2 going to execute'
command2 going to execute
+ echo 'command3 going to execute'
command3 going to execute
+ set +x    check the given function.

Comment: ok so what's wrong why function not executing properly?

Comment: Try `function execute_all_cmd` { ---- } in the script, Note : remove the parenthesis `()` like that .

Comment: @Kalanidhi Tried but no luck!But one interesting thing i found let you desscusse in chat

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50092/discussion-between-jayesh-and-kalanidhi)