# Is there any limit for line of code in function of different BASH version

Tags: linux, bash

This question arrived from my another post [look](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22505834/taking-log-of-command-output-from-inside-script-not-working-as-expected)

Having try following script in my Ubuntu machine with bash version `GNU bash, version 4.2.25(1)-release (i686-pc-linux-gnu)` and Linux kernel version `Linux 3.2.0-60`

```
#!/bin/bash
execute_no_lines()
{
   echo "going to execute line 1"
   echo "going to execute line 2"
   echo "going to execute line 3"
   echo "going to execute line 4"
   .............................
   ..............so on upto 1000
   lines........................
}
execute_no_lines
```

It works fine and `print` 1000 lines.

Now i have one target board with runs with linux kernel version `Linux 2.6.30`
 and bash version `GNU bash, version 3.2.0(1)-release (sh-unknown-linux-gnu)`

when i run same above script in my target board then it cause segmentation fault

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Now i reduce the lines in script function upto `446` then it works fine but if i add single line after 446 line number then segmentation fault occurs.

**Note:** In above script, for example purpose i put `echo` statement in function but my actual script contain many more like `echo`,`commands`,`if_else` etc.

So i want to know about, Is there any line limit in bash and linux kernel for different version?

Comment: Is this related to ulimit?

Comment: The shell function needs to fit in memory. If bash runs out of memory, it is possible that it will segfault. Had there been an imposed line limit, it would have given you an error message.

Comment: @Newbrict already set ulimit to unlimited.

Comment: It's a bug, not a deliberately imposed limit.

Comment: Could you provide a backtrace for the segmentation fault? I compiled that specific version (bash-3.2.tar.gz) and ran a bigger script, and it didn't fail, so it would be useful if you provided more information.

This tutorial shows how to get a backtrace from the core dump: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/httpserv/ihsdiag/get_backtrace.html